# Logging Data After INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY and UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large database of subscriber information.  New subscribers join, some change their information, others cancel.  I want to keep track of these changes every time I update the subscriber file.  I never delete a canceled subscription, I turn their 'eligibility' to false.

Here is the 'current' snapshot of a test database I created.  I am going to change 'doctor' to 'colonel', set the lawyer's eligibility to false, then change 'RN' to 'BSN' and change his phone number from '444-5555' to '444-1234'

[image]

Here is the updated subscriber list:

[image: Updated Subscribers]

And the two SQL statements I run back-to-back to do the UPDATES and INSERT

Query 1

```
 INSERT INTO test_existing (test_existing.emp_id, test_existing.title, 
 test_existing.phone, test_existing.eligible)
   SELECT t.emp_id, t.title, t.phone, t.eligible from test_new t
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE test_existing.emp_id =t.emp_id, 
   test_existing.title = t.title, test_existing.phone =t.phone;
```

Query 2

```
UPDATE test_existing
SET test_existing.eligible = 'FALSE' where test_existing.emp_id not in 
 (select test_new.emp_id from test_new)
```

These queries produce a table that includes all the changes:

[image: Data Log after Update and Insert]

I run a series of simple mySQL triggers to capture the changes. Here they are:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert_test` AFTER INSERT ON `test_existing`
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO data_log (action, timestamp,emp_id, title, phone, eligible)
    VALUES('after_insert', NOW(),NEW.emp_id,NEW.title, NEW.phone, NEW. 
    eligible);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `after_update_test` AFTER UPDATE ON `test_existing`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO data_log (action, timestamp,emp_id, title, phone, eligible)
    VALUES('after_update', NOW(),NEW.emp_id,NEW.title, NEW.phone, NEW. 
    eligible);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `before_insert_test` BEFORE INSERT ON `test_existing`
   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO data_log (action, timestamp,emp_id, title, phone, eligible)
     VALUES('before_insert', NOW(),NEW.emp_id,NEW.title, NEW.phone, NEW. 
     eligible);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `before_update_test` BEFORE UPDATE ON `test_existing`
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO data_log (action, timestamp,emp_id, title, phone, eligible)
    VALUES('before_update', NOW(),NEW.emp_id,NEW.title, NEW.phone, NEW. 
    eligible);
END
```

These triggers produce this data log file

[image: Data Log File]

Lots of information - some of it useful, some not.  But I would have expected to see the 'before_update' for the 'colonel' to be 'doctor', and the 'before' update for the lawyer's eligibility to be 'TRUE' instead of 'FALSE' - same is true for the RN to BSN and the phone number.

Is it because of the order my two queries are executed, or the execution order of the triggers?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are MySQL extensions to triggers; they are not case-sensitive.
In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used; there is no old row. In a DELETE trigger, only OLD.col_name can be used; there is no new row. In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to the columns of the row after it is updated. - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Ah, thanks - new to data logging, did not realize there was an an OLD key word.  Works great!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your before update trigger use OLD instead of NEW:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `before_update_test` BEFORE UPDATE ON `test_existing`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO data_log (action, timestamp,emp_id, title, phone, eligible)
VALUES('before_update', NOW(),OLD.emp_id,OLD.title, OLD.phone, OLD. 
eligible);
END
```

NEW refers to the new value that is going to be inserted. OLD refers to the existing value.

Comment: Ah, thanks - new to data logging, did not realize there was an an OLD key word.  Works great!!